# uiautomatorviewer hierarchy viewer error on mac

Tags: android, macos, uiautomatorviewer

I can run my android automatorviewer smoothly but I get hierarchy viewer error after capturing the android device's current screen. The internal error show "Unexpected error while obtaining UI hierarchy java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException".
[This is the error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmMrz.png)

My android device version is android 10
Current Android SDK version 26.1.1
macOS Catalina 10.15.5
Java version 1.8.0_252

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Did you find a solution?